# proc_open gives different output in Apache2 vs CLI

Tags: php, apache, wkhtmltopdf

I am using [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert HTML documents to PDF files on our website.  I am using the following code in my PHP class:

```
<?php

$pdfConv = proc_open('wkhtmltopdf -q -s letter --no-background --print-media-type --title Test - -', [
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
    2 => array('pipe', 'w')
], $pipes, '/tmp', NULL, [
    'bypass_shell' => true
]);

if(is_resource($pdfConv)){
    // Send STDIN
    fwrite($pipes[0], $htmlData);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    // Receive STDOUT
    $pdfFile = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // Set headers and send file to browser to be downloaded

    // Close process
    proc_close($pdfConv);
}
```

NOTE: For testing purposes I did `$htmlData = file_get_contents('http://google.com');`.

When I browsed to the page in my web browser and clicked "download PDF", I got the following output:

[image: Messed up PDF File]

([Download original PDF file](https://mega.nz/#!LkFSnALA!nvwB9hQOIerswvvbJPvXNUjdxudcUNijATzfextALgI))

Trying to figure what was wrong, I took to the command-line and ran:

```
wkhtmltopdf -q -s letter --no-background --print-media-type --title Test http://google.com /tmp/google.pdf
```

This worked perfectly, so I wondered if something was wrong with PHP.  I typed `php -a` and pasted the above code into the command-line and ran it, and it worked perfectly.

Here is what the PDF should look like:

[image: Good PDF File]

([Download original PDF file](https://mega.nz/#!u512VKJZ!a4AIkK8WpVilTHBYfSKdej3QzIk-qxlAnX0iAhp3mLA))

Why would running the same code from Apache (via my web browser) give a different PDF than running on the command line directly?  Where did these weird characters come from?  How can I even debug this?

Comment: Looks like something related to environment variables. See if the output of command `export` is the same both in shell and when called by PHP in Apache. `PATH` is often the vilan, you may want to set its value to match the one in the shell before running the program.

Comment: @Havenard: I see a few differences!  Other than things like `TERM` and `PATH`, the only *big* difference is that shell says `LANG=en_US.UTF8`, whereas PHP says `LANG="C"`.

Comment: @Havenard: DUDE!  I've been staring at this for hours!  That was it!  I don't know what `LANG="C"` is, but that was the issue.

Comment: @Havenard: Do you wanna write up an answer (and set some more rep)?  Or should I just answer my own question?

Comment: Nah, go ahead. I'm too sleepy to do that, its almost 4 in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283946/proc-open-gives-different-output-in-apache2-vs-cli#comment48665956_30283946), I figured out the problem.  I ran `export` from my command line and via `proc_open` in PHP and compared the output.

On my command line, I saw `LANG=en_US.UTF8` but from PHP it said `LANG="C"`.

The solution was to set the `LANG` value in the environment in `proc_open`

```
$pdfConv = proc_open('wkhtmltopdf -q -s letter --no-background --print-media-type --title Test - -', [
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
    2 => array('pipe', 'w')
], $pipes, '/tmp', [
    'LANG' => 'en_US.UTF8'
], [
    'bypass_shell' => true
]);
```

Comment: God, yes, thank you! I've been struggling with this for hours now, thank you so much for going back to your thread and replying! I almost missed the discussion between you and @Havenard.